# Pass Javascript and PHP variables through PHP Form

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Been searching all day, found items similar but completely stuck...

I want to pass a Google Maps Autocomplete Result (latlng) into a PHP Form along with PHP variables through one submit (not two buttons, i.e. to put JS variable in hidden field then submit form via submit button)

Code at present:

```
    <?php    

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
  // echo vars if they are working...
  echo "passed data <br>";
  echo $_POST['first_name'] . "<br>";
  echo $_POST['geocode'] . "<br>";    

  // Get variables, check data and store into DB...    
}    

?>
```

Then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var geocoder;

  function initialize() {

    // Search options
    var searchOptions = { 
      componentRestrictions : {country: 'nz'},
      types: ['geocode']
    };

    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, searchOptions);

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  }

  function codeAddress() {

    var address = document.getElementById('pac-input').value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {    
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {        
        document.getElementById('geocode').value = (results[0].geometry.location);             
      } else {
        //alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }

    });

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 

  function submitthis() {

    codeAddress();

  }

  </script>

  <script>

  $(function(){ // Document Ready

  });

  </script>
```

Finally:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="google-text-input.php" method="post" >

    First Name<input name="first_name" type="text"><br>

    Address<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box"><br>



    <input id="geocode" name="geocode" type="text" value="null"><br> <!-- to be hidden -->

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitthis()"><br>


  </form>
```

I'd preferably like when I hit the Submit button it stores Google Maps result into hidden, submits form to same page then I can pull all php vars and store. I'm open to an approach which upon submit puts the javascript part into the url where I can pull PHP vars via POST and just GET the Google Result in the URL.

The only thing I can see which isn't working in the above is the form gets submitted before my codeAddress() has completed. As if I put return false to prevent form submit it updates my hidden field.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yeah, I can do! I've looked at preventing the ENTER key on the address and onblur() of the address field to update my hidden field (shown at present), just not sure if this is the right approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I'm not very familiar with Google's Geocoding api, but there are a couple of ways you can do this.

**First Method**

Append hidden input elements inside your form. This is probably the closest to what you are describing in your question.

Here is a simplified form:

```
<form name="testForm" action="test.php" 
  method="post" onSubmit="return doSubmit();">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Adding the `return doSubmit();` means that you can call that function, and cancel sending the form if you need to.

Here is the accompanying javascript:

```
function doSubmit() {
    var latval = 42; // Use the geolocation values you want here.
    var lat = document.createElement("input");
    lat.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    lat.setAttribute("value", latval);
    lat.setAttribute("name", "geo[lat]");
    document.forms["testForm"].appendChild(lat);
    return true;
    //Note: to stop the form from submitting, you can just return false.
}
```

If using jQuery, this becomes easier. You don't need to add the `onSubmit` field to the form. Just assign a unique name, or an id to the submit button.

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $("input[name=submit]").click(function(e) {
       var latVal = 42; // Get geo vals here.
       $("form[name=testForm]").appendChild(
           "<input type='hidden' name='geo[lat]' value='" + latVal + "' />"
       );
    });
```

});

Here is a simple test php file:

```
//test.php
<?php

if (isset($_POST["geo"])) {
    echo "LAT IS: ".$_POST["geo"]["lat"];
}
?>
```

When you click on the button, it will append a hidden input to the form, and send that along with the rest of the POST data. You can assign array type values to form names, and it will convert it to be an array in the PHP `$_POST` array.

This example will print "LAT IS: 42" when you click the button.

**Second Method**

This is the best one. Use ajax and json with jQuery (ajax can be done in raw javascript, but it [isn't fun](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript--net-4855)!

For this, I will use a simpler form, and add a div:

```
<form name="testForm">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The php just echos `$_POST["geo"]["lat"]`.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[name=testForm]").submit(function (e) {
        // Prevent form from submitting.
        e.preventDefault();
        // Create a js object.
        var jso = {};
        // Add a geo object.
        jso['geo'] = {};
        // Define its lat value.
        jso['geo']['lat'] = 42;
        // Add all other values you want to POST in the method.
        // You can also just do jso.lat = 42, then change the php accordingly.
        // Send the ajax query.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: jso,
            success: function(data, status) {
                $("#output").html("<p>" + data + "</p>"); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In a nutshell, this is how easy ajax is. Clicking the submit button in this example will set the html of the div to 42.

Comment: Thanks Steven, so using the example code above everything works fine - it's when I go and run the Google Maps Geocoder under the form submit click() it doesn't work, it's as though the geocoder function takes to long and it submits the form before the geocoder function has finished processing. I hope that makes sense, I'm keen to give the AJAX method a go tomorrow and see how that works.

Comment: @sprintcar78a, It looks like when you call geocoder.geocode, the second parameter is a function that runs after you've gotten your results. Do the ajax request inside the geocoder.geocode callback function, and you should be able to add the results to your ajax query from there.

Comment: I need a trigger to run that func., if you type in an address (it autocompletes) & a user hits ENTER it submits the form so the geocode func. isn't be processed (or too slowly) & the page gets submitted. I think we may have to prevent the default action of the form submit & send it through jQuery or Ajax within the geocode function as you've suggested. 
Another work around I've got working is to run the geocode function on the address input onblur() & prevent the ENTER key from working on that input. Thanks so much for your input, jQuery was helpful & I'm keen to familiarise myself with Ajax!